# npm publish stuck (using yarn)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to publish a new package.
I'm using ES6, so I'm first transpiling my files using babel.

I'm stuck on this step:

[image]

This takes forever (waited more than an hour). No error messages, nothing happens.

Here's my package.json prepublish script and main.js:

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "babel -d lib/ src/"
  }
  "main": "./lib/index.js"
```

My index.js has some ES6 imports and one module.export.
Here's my .npmignore file:

```
src/
yarn.lock
node_modules
```

I dont have any big filex in the directory (whole directory excluding node_modules has less than 1MB).

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Did you try using npm instead of yarn to publish? You could also try adding the `--verbose` flag for yarn, not certain if it will output anything helpful or not when publishing.

Comment: No, I haven't. After I installed yarn, npm is not recognized as a command on my MacOS.

Comment: Well that's no good. I'd personally attack that first. Using homebrew for everything can be helpful. But yeah, try the verbose flag.

Comment: Also, you should assume this is a yarn issue until proven otherwise. This looks like the same issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1494

Comment: And [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/610) and [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1694), which looks to be the canonical reference. Looks to be a known yarn bug with no plans to fix :/

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! That might be the case. Just one more quick question so I don't have to create another question :). Any idea why npm is not recognized as bash (CLI) command after installing yarn? I did use homebrew for installing both npm(node) and yarn.

Comment: Honestly, no clue. I'm almost certain that's not an intended effect of installing yarn. I'd suggest re-installing node to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Shawn Erquhart, this is not an npm issue. It's caused by yarn package manager that I am using.

Related yarn issues:

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1494

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/610

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1694

I fixed it by using npm instead of yarn. (Had to reinstall node since npm wasn't recognized as a bash(CLI) command after installing yarn).